# How can I make a user defined "Other" in a field with Choices in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm coding up a model in Django and I need some choices - but I would like to let the user choose 'Other' and then type in their own choice too. How can this be done in Django?

```
class Client(models.Model):
ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('publicly_traded', 'Publicly Traded Company'),
    ('limited_liability', 'Limited Liability Company'),
    ('partnership', 'Partnership'),
    ('ngo', 'NGO'),
)
...
entity_type = models.CharField(choices=ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a proper ForeignKey with [django-autocomplete-light v.3](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light).

It has an excellent feature of creating new choices [on the fly](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#creation-of-new-choices-in-the-autocomplete-form).

Moreover, you can [adjust the queryset](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#create-an-autocomplete-view) to serve only the choices you have marked as appropriate (in a boolean field, for example) and ignore any others but accept new choices (if that makes sense).

This can also be achieved using [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to).

You may even use a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) in order to have control over the user's inserted data vs the data that would otherwise be in the choices tuple.

I consider [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) an excellent tool for providing rarely changing options for a foreign key.

According to my experience, overriding and messing with the basic purpose of choices, provides a mediocre result which involves a lot of redundant coding.

Comment: django-autocomplete-light seems to duplicate some functionality that I'm using django-easy-select2 for. Is it worth it moving to dal?

You're right, I'll try and see if using static choices is good enough first.

Comment: @randomshinichi Actually I have not used any other but dal so I cannot compare. It  is possible that it is somehow full featured but there is nothing I need and it is not covered. Anyway, the best strategy is to start simply and enhance when needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a field with `choices` you probably do not want to add `dirty` values that are not in your specified options.

When I had to implement something like this, I added another `CharField` to my model that would specifically be used to store other choices from my main field, e.g.:

```
my_choices_field = CharField(choices=MY_CHOICES, max_length=64)
my_choices_field_other = CharField(max_length=64)
```

Then, in my template, I'd render both of them and in the `Form` I'd validate that the user could only fill one of those fields, e.g.

```
def clean(self):
    ...
    if my_choices_field and my_choices_field_other:  # Both are filled, raise error
        raise ValidationError("Please select one or type other 'my_choice', not both.")
```

If you really want to use the same field, you'd probably need to work some JavaScript to manually add options to your `select` and then work around the Django validation of your `choices` since it'll probably block it.